# How to validate PayPal data with IPN when using non-hosted PayPal button

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, paypal, e-commerce, paypal-ipn

I am rather new to PHP and adding payment gateways

However, I want to learn and am having a go at a small shop with a Paypal buy now button which is linked to a PHP cookies cart

It is working fine and shows a list of the items in the cart, however I am worried it is not secure enough and someone could change the amounts or add their email address so that they receive funds

I would like to integrate the instant payment notification (IPN) : https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-info-outside

Do I need to do much more than follow the above instructions and make an IPN in the merchant account?

I am a bit confused about what the POST code means and how to integrate it into my button code

Please could someone explain what I need to change in my Paypal button code below so that I can make the payment system secure? I keep breaking it

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<!--input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Something Cool">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="5">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="1"-->
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach (json_decode($_COOKIE['cart_items_cookie']) as $key => $value) {
    $i++;
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_name_'.$i.'" value="'.$value->name.'">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="amount_'.$i.'" value="'.$value->price.'">';
 }
?>
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mysite.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Order#21874">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<!--<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php //echo $_GET['total'];?    > "> -->
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Any help or point in the right direction much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do would be to use the [Express Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReference/) instead of Payments Standard (HTML forms).  This requires more programming and working with API calls, however, I have a [PayPal PHP class library](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) you can use to make all of the calls very quick and easy for you.

Express Checkout completely hides everything about the payment and it has a lot more features available to it than Standard does.

If you want to stick with Standard, you can build a hosted button by creating the button from within your PayPal account, and make sure to select the option to "Save the button at PayPal."  That is what makes it hosted.

Then you'll still get HTML to paste into your site where you want the payment button to show up, but it will only have a few lines, and one of those lines will show a "hosted_button_id".

This secures the button from tampering like you mentioned, but it limits customization you can do with your checkout in general.

Comment: hey thanks for your help and sorry for the late reply. I actually realised I should have used the checkout API after i asked this question and am working on that now, thanks for the link I will have a look, do you think I will be able to do it with limited PHP knowledge? It is at a basic level I would say.. I have lots of html and css knowledge but I am just learning most things. I used unhosted to that I could link the button to my cart as like you say customisation is limited otherwise